# Android - caching bitmaps in memory before drawing to canvas

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I have a view that has `onDraw()` called several times per second.  There are seven bitmaps that can be drawn, but only one is drawn at once.

When a bitmap is showing, it's position is changing several times a second and thus it is redrawn constantly.  There is no significant slowdown when this happens.  However, when the image changes, there is a noticeable momentary slowdown before it is drawn for the first time.  This happens even though the bitmap was decoded in the constructor.

I assume this has something to do with caching and the image not being properly loaded into memory.

**My Question:** Is there some way I can ready the image in memory before the `canvas.drawBitmap()` call?

I don't even need to load all 7 into memory at once: at any given time there are only 2 possible candidates for the next image.

```
public class MyView extends View {
  private Bitmap mBitmapSlices[] = new Bitmap[7];
  private Rect mSourceRect = new Rect();
  private Rect mDestRect = new Rect();

  private void init(Context context) {
    // initialize array of bitmap slices
    mBitmapSlices[0] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bitmap1);
    mBitmapSlices[1] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bitmap2);
    // etc.....
  }

  //stuff like constructors that call init and what-not

  @Override
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // lots of logic

    if (condition) index = 0;  //simplified, there are actually 7 images
    else index = 1;

    Bitmap bmp = mBitmapSlices[index];

    //This is the issue  --- This call only takes longer the first frame when index changes
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, mSourceRect, mDestRect, null);

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're looking for `Bitmap.prepareToDraw()`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#prepareToDraw()

Comment: And what if you create new canvas and draw all bitmaps into it at `init`? Then by the first call of `onDraw` the bitmaps will be ready.

Comment: The same as you wrote in your own answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/22870000/2768194), but not at first frame, but in `init`.

Comment: And one more question: did you call `prepareToDraw` in `init` or in `onDraw`? If you call this in `onDraw`, then it will have no sense. Call it in `init` for all bitmaps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this qualifies as an answer, but what I ultimately did to fix this is a terrible hack, and I wish I could have found a way around it.  I simply added this to `OnDraw()`:

```
if (firstFrame) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmapSlices[0], mSourceRect, mDestRect, null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmapSlices[1], mSourceRect, mDestRect, null);
    //etc...

    firstTime = false;
}
```

So, I draw them once at the beginning, then they stay in memory (even though I draw over them after).  Frankly, I think this code is disgusting, but it's the best I was able to do.